# Can anyone help this beginner figure out this basic Python issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm new to Python and started practicing and have been doing okay until I got stuck on this problem. I think the 'else' statement is the issue but I've tried many variations and can't figure it out. Any advice is most welcome to this noob. Here is a screenshot of the error and code. Thanks! https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLzrf.png

Comment: Please know that we would rather post code snippets instead of a image of code.

Answer (score 1):

use keyword `elif` instead of `else`. `else` does not need any expression

Answer (score 0):

Use `elif` instead of `else` because `else` doesn't use expressions after it and put `else` after the `elif` containing a error message or something. You cannot put something like this:

```
if a > b:


elif a < b:
```

because there is no `else` statement for if `a` and `b` are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `else` statement in the wrong way, because it cannot contain a condition. If you want to add a second condition use `elif` instead. And use `else` only when you want to define a statement to execute when no other if statement was `True`.

```
if 1 == 1:
    # your statement
elif 1 == 2:
    # your other statement
else:
    # your statement if none of the above was true
```